# How to remove specific tag with class in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in Ruby on Rails application, How can I remove specific html tag with some attribute as shown as below :-

```
post = Post.find(1646).content

 => "<p>this is just another update</p><p data-f-id=\"pbf\" style=\"text-align: center; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 30px; opacity: 0.65; font-family: sans-serif;\">Powered by <a href=\"any href link" title=\"xyz\">remove it</a></p>"
```

I have to totally remove this below paragraph from above content:-

```
<p data-f-id=\"pbf\" style=\"text-align: center; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 30px; opacity: 0.65; font-family: sans-serif;\">Powered by <a href=\"any href link" title=\"xyz\">remove it</a></p>
```

How can I identify this `<p data-f-id=\"pbf\"` with using regex or something else. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Use a html parser like nokogiri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610). Use an HTML parser instead.

There are several popular HTML parsing libraries in ruby. Here is one way to do it, using [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri):

```
post = Post.find(1646).content
document = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse post
document.css('p[data-f-id=pbf]').remove

document.to_s
  #=> "<p>this is just another update</p>"
```